# application getting slower over a period on iis

Tags: iis

We have hosted application on IIS 8,it becomes slower over a period of time.When app pool recycles after 29 hours it is back to normal performance but we are not getting outofmemory exception.

application getting slower over a period and is back to normal performance on default app pool recycle

Comment: Learn what is profiling, and then act on that.

Answer (score 0):

1. How slow is it ? Don't back on manual interpretation here. Check IIS logs (Default Location: C:\inetpub\logs\logfiles\w3svc_website_ID) and look at the time-taken field. The time-taken will be in milliseconds and time field would be in UTC.
2. Based on the IIS logs, set up a FREB rule as per - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/docast/2016/04/28/troubleshooting-iis-request-performance-slowness-issues-using-freb-tracing/
3. In order to analyze FREB log, open it in IE and click on compact view. Observe the time field on the right hand side. Once you observe a definite jump in time field, that's your culprit. if you do not observe any changes in the time field, then the last module is the possible culprit.
4. You can also capture manual hang dumps of the w3wp process using debug diag during the time of issue. Install debug diag from - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924
5. Capture a manual hang dump during the time of issue. Search specifically for "Create a user dump file for a process" in this page and follow the steps mentioned under it - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/919792/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-a-process-that-h
6. Once you have the required dump file, run debug diag analysis engine on this and look out for the results. Let me know if you need help in dump analysis